# How to terminate a process and its parent from command prompt

Tags: windows, command, prompt

I have a process that is launched from command prompt - file.bat, although its parent cmd.exe needs to be terminated as well. The only problem is there are other instances of cmd.exe is there any way of terminating the process file.bat - without deleting other instances of cmd.exe

(I can't simply terminate the cmd.exe process, as I dont know the PID in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try parsing the output of the PsList utility from Sysinternals.

You can get it from:
http://technet.microsoft.com -> search for "sysinternals"

When you run "PsList -t" you'll see a list of processes, with children indented from the left margin. Here's a snippet:

[image: sample output]

The first numeric column is the PID. You didn't mention what kind of language you're writing your script in, but it shouldn't be too hard to iterate over the lines, and use a stack-like structure to store the current descent-path. When you reach the PID of the desired process, you'll be able to examine the stack to get the parent info.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but its the best anyone's come up with! :) Thanks

Comment: Just to point it out: http://live.sysinternals.com is a quick alternative download for the same set of tools.

Comment: @0xC0000022L that site seems to be current (the modified times match the dates on technet). However, I'd advise checking the digital signatures on the executables just in case.

Comment: @Kelvin: you should **always** check the signatures regardless, so that's not specific to that site. However, as you may or may not know Sysinternals was bought by Microsoft years ago and that explains why that seemingly unrelated site is a perfectly fine source for the exact same tools. Just use your web search fu to find out more about Microsoft buying Sysinternals and how that live.sysinternals.com website came to be. Also see the [WHOIS data](http://whois.domaintools.com/sysinternals.com).